# How to create different ggpair scatterplot limits for the columns/rows?

Tags: r, ggpairs

In ggpairs, how can I create different scales in cells? I created the plots, but what the function I have now is using the same scales for the scatterplots. I need to compare multiple different ggpair plots to see how they end up evolving, but this will only make sense if they have the same scales on the plots.

[image]

This is what I've been using to create the scales.

```
limitRange <- function(data, mapping, ...) { 
  ggplot(data = data, mapping = mapping, ...) + 
    geom_point(...,size=.5) + 
    scale_y_continuous(limits = c(min(data), max(data))) +
    scale_x_continuous(limits = c(min(data), max(data))) 
}
```

Thank you for any ideas!!

Comment: But what is about the density plots? If you change the y-scales it could be that the lines can't be seen anymore.

Comment: That's true, but I really care about the scatterplots